# Parameter of floating ip on bootstrap

Tags: cloudify

What are the possible parameters of this value

> custom ([ "associateFloatingIpOnBootstrap" : "true" ])

Can i change this value after the bootstrap

Can i associate the floating ip after on recipe

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The possible values are only true and false, but Cloudify 2.7 supports setting floating IPs from lifecycle events. See here:
http://getcloudify.org/guide/2.7/clouddrivers/network.html

> Support for Floating IPs
>
> Cloudify Network Cloud Driver provides API for working with floating
>   IPs. This means the recipe lifecycle events can use floating IPs
>   programmatically

Note that this functionality is only available for Openstack based clouds. For other clouds, you may have to implement the network driver functionality yourself.